# How to find which jQuery plug-in is attached to an element in a page?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am trying to understand how the "view source" collapsing button in the following page works:

http://jqueryui.com/tabs/

Is it using jQueryUI? Where is the selector that plugs the collapsing functionality to it?

In general, is there any way to find out if any JQuery JavaScript plugin effect is attached to a component by using tools such as FireBug?

Update:

The page I am referring to happened to be a sample about one of jQueryUI Widgets, but my question is about one specific part of the page that might not have anything to do with jQueryUI:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Is it using JQueryUI?

Yes. If you see jQueryUI referral in view-source by right clicking on any document with a browser, it means it's using jQuery + jQuery UI. jQuery UI is an additional javascript library used with jQuery core.

> Where is the selector that plugs the collapsing functionality to it?

The code $(function() { $( "#tabs" ).tabs(); });does the whole job of collapsing,etc for the tab. That's why jQueryUI is for.

> In general, is there any way to find out if any JQuery JavaScript
>   plugin effect is attached to a component by using tools such as
>   FireBug?

If you see any of the words like Accordion, Tabs, Dialog, Datepicker in the javascript command, it means the component is attached to a jQueryUI library.

Comment: I am not referring to Tabs widget example in the page. Please see the update question and the screen shot.